# Euler numbers formula

Tags: linear-algebra

In this formula for Euler numbers:

\begin{equation*}
A_n = i^{n+1}\sum _{k=1}^{n+1} \sum _{j=0}^k{k\choose{j}} \frac{(-1)^j(k-2j)^{n+1}}{2^ki^kk},
\end{equation*}

what is $i$? I have to generate the $n^{th}$ Euler number, and I don't have $i$.

It is not the imaginary unit, is it?

Comment: Actually, it is.  So... yeah.  But this is not a standard formula; the OEIS should have others.

Comment: There must be better algorithms than using the formula you state. Perhaps this will have a better algorithm: http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/JIS/VOL4/CHEN/AlgBE2.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I'll check that pdf too!

Comment: Note that the algorithm in the paper mentioned by @Moron can be implemented with just a one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is $\sqrt{-1}$.  They will all divide out in the end.  A derivation of your formula is [here](http://www.voofie.com/content/117/an-explicit-formula-for-the-euler-zigzag-numbers-updown-numbers-from-power-series/).  The $i$'s come from changing the $\sin(x)$ function to its definition in terms of $\exp(x)$

Comment: Thank you! And is this the simplest formula to generate them? I didn't find any other simpler formula

Comment: Wow! I found this: $E_{n} = 2^nE_{n}(\frac{1}{2})$ where $E_{n}(x)$ is the $n-th$ Euler polynomial

Comment: A lot of references are found on OEIS:  http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/?q=A000364&sort=0&fmt=0&language=english&go=Search